# PowerShell Loop through nested json and remove property

Tags: json, powershell

I am getting some json data from a API, however I don't need most of this data. I am trying to remove some fields so that the when I save this data as a json file it isn't so large. I doesnt seem to be removing any of the fields I am trying to remove.

**Code:**

```bsh
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json" -Method GET
$Obj = ConvertFrom-Json $Response

$Obj.PSObject.Properties.Remove('booster')
$Obj.PSObject.Properties.Remove('cards')

$Obj | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File ./All-Sets-Data.json -Force
```

**Json:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "10E": {
      "baseSetSize": 383,
      "block": "Core Set",
      "booster": "@{default=}",
      "cards": "",
      "code": "10E",
      ...
    },
    "2ED": {
      "baseSetSize": 302,
      "block": "Core Set",
      "booster": "@{default=}",
      "cards": "",
      "code": "2ED",
      ...
    },
    "2XM": {
      "baseSetSize": 332,
      "booster": "@{default=}",
      "cards": "",
      "code": "2XM",
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Obj.data.'10E'.PSObject.Properties.Remove('booster')
$Obj.data.'10E'.PSObject.Properties.Remove('cards')
$Obj.data.'2ED'.PSObject.Properties.Remove('booster')
# and so on
```

The above code snippet should work. However, you can do all in a one step by calling the following (recursive) function `RemoveProperty`:

```
Function RemoveProperty {
  param (
    # A PSCustomObject
    [Parameter( Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline )] $Object,
    # A list of property names to remove
    [Parameter( Mandatory )] [string[]]$PropList,
    # recurse?
    [Parameter()] [Switch]$Recurse
  )
  # Write-Host $Object  -ForegroundColor Cyan
  foreach ( $Prop in $PropList ) {
    $Object.PSObject.Properties.Remove($prop)
  }
  # Write-Host $Object  -ForegroundColor Green
  if ( $Recurse.IsPresent ) {
    foreach ($ObjValue in $Object.PSObject.Properties.Value) {
      # Write-Host $ObjValue  -ForegroundColor Yellow
      if ( $ObjValue.GetType().Name -eq 'PSCustomObject' ) {
        $ObjValue | RemoveProperty -PropList $PropList -Recurse
      }
    }
  }
}
```

# sample usage:

```
$Obj = ConvertFrom-Json $Response

RemoveProperty -Object $Obj -PropList 'booster','cards' -Recurse

$Obj | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File ./All-Sets-Data.json -Force
```

(Please note that the `RemoveProperty` function contains some `Write-Host` in commented lines; originally used used for debugging purposes).